# Read Excel file using Headers Apache POI Spring Boot

Tags: excel, spring-boot, header, apache-poi, xlsx

How to Read Excel file(**xlsx**) using Headers **Apache POI** , **Spring Boot**  !!!.I know we can read using row iterator and cell iterator. I want to read using the header.

This is how I read **xlsx** file using **row iterator** and **cell iterator**

```
    InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("myfile.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);

    XSSFWorkbook test = new XSSFWorkbook();

    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow row;
    XSSFCell cell;


    Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

    while (rows.hasNext())
    {
        row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
        Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

        while (cells.hasNext())
        {

            cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();

            if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {

                 System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + " ");
            } else if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {

                DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

                Double impactMultiple = cell.getNumericCellValue();

                System.out.print(impactMultiple+" ");

            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

But How to read using Header ??

**code**:

Image for Reference 1:

[image: Screen Shot]

Image for Reference 2:

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Only read the first row, if that's the one with the header in?

Comment: For example: use `sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue()` to read the first column header.

Comment: This won't work in my case as Headers values  will change their order i.e header columns are dynamic please see image for reference

Answer (score 0):

You can map value by header by convert excel file to json first and then you can map to object with object mapper

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.